# Angular await not waiting

Tags: angular, promise, async-await

I have a bit of code with `await`-s set like this:

```js
async calculateDeletionResidualsData(res) {
    //console.log("resss is:");
    //console.log(res);

    let selectedCountries = this.countriesList.filter(c => c.selected);
    let selectedIndicators = this.indicatorsList.filter(i => i.selected);

    await selectedCountries.forEach(async c => {
        // taking each (selected) country

        await selectedIndicators.forEach(async i => {
            // taking each (selected) indicator

            // Form the series for the calculation of residuals
            let series = [];
            deletionResidualsRelevantYears.forEach(y => {
                series.push(res[c.label][y][i.label][0]);
            });
            // Calculate deletion residuals
            let drr = await util.calculateDeletionResidualsStatistics(
                deletionResidualsRelevantYears.length,
                series,
                this.deletionResidualsService
            );

            this.drr[c.label][i.label] = drr;
        });
    });

    console.log("setting qrReady to true");
    this.qrReady = true;
}
```

I can clearly see that the calls to the `util.calculateDeletionResidualsStatistics` are still being made in the network tab of my browser, but I also see that the `console.log("setting qrReady to true");` has already been fired, and it shouldn't be fired. Why are all these awaits skipped and jumped over to the last line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await` won't work for loops that use callbacks. Don’t ever use await with forEach. Use a for-loop (or any loop without a callback) instead

`forEach` is not promise-aware. It cannot support async and await. You cannot use await in forEach.

[Learn more...](https://medium.com/dailyjs/the-pitfalls-of-async-await-in-array-loops-cf9cf713bfeb)

Comment: I used for(let i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {} type of loop and it looks like it works.....I need to control again, but this seemes to have done the job.

Comment: async/await won't work for loops that use callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

`await` only works on functions that return a `Promise`. `forEach` does not. **Assuming** `util.calculateDeletionResidualsStatistics` returns a `Promise`, write your code like this instead:

```js
calculateDeletionResidualsData(res) {
    //console.log("resss is:");
    //console.log(res);

    let selectedCountries = this.countriesList.filter(c => c.selected);
    let selectedIndicators = this.indicatorsList.filter(i => i.selected);

    selectedCountries.forEach( c => {
        // taking each (selected) country

        selectedIndicators.forEach(async i => {
            // taking each (selected) indicator

            // Form the series for the calculation of residuals
            let series = [];
            deletionResidualsRelevantYears.forEach(y => {
                series.push(res[c.label][y][i.label][0]);
            });
            // Calculate deletion residuals
            let drr = await util.calculateDeletionResidualsStatistics(
                deletionResidualsRelevantYears.length,
                series,
                this.deletionResidualsService
            );
            this.drr[c.label][i.label] = drr;
        });
    });

    console.log("setting qrReady to true");
    this.qrReady = true;
}
```

If not, please edit your post and I'll try to provide a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with `await` if you have a collection of promises, and use a `map()` operation to create an array of promises.

```js
    await Promise.all(selectedCountries.map(async c => {
        await Promise.all(selectedIndicators.map(async i => {
            let drr = await util.calculateDeletionResidualsStatistics(...);
            // ...
        });
    });

    console.log('printed after everything is finished');
```

Keep in mind that `Promise.all()` will resolve an array of results after all of the inner promises have resolved. The order of those promises is unpredictable as they resolve in parallel.

You will end up with nested `Promise.all()` that will resolve in batches before the top level `Promise.all()` resolves.

Since it looks like you are discarding the results of the outer promises, then I don't see a real issue here with the order. You just want to run some code after everything is done.